# Creating a mod_rewrite rule in an htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory

I am trying to create a `mod_rewrite` rule to direct people to a sub-folder. Currently the code looks as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abcsite.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www\.abcsite\.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ /abc/$1 [L]
```

The redirect works if the user types `www.abcsite.com`, but not if they type `abc.com`. Is there something that I am missing or should do differently to make sure the user goes to the correct folder (regardless of how they type the URL)?

Side note: The `htaccess` file that I am dealing with is a Joomla file, so all contents of it deal with another Joomla site. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @Donut – I think you shouldn't edit the rules. OTOH, OP probably meant `abcsite.com`, not `abc.com`.

Comment: @aaz If you look at the edit history, you'll see that I left the rules unchanged. I just put them into a code block, which separated each rule onto its own line as the OP intended.

Comment: @Donut – Weird: in the revisions screen it's showing that slashes were added to the second regex. The source for the original version has them, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have conditions for that.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abcsite.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www\.abcsite\.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/.*$
```

All above rules will pass only its abcsite.com

You add following rules also then it work for abc.com too.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} abc.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^!www\.abc\.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/abc/.*$ 
RewriteRule (.*)$ /abc/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a stray `!` in your second condition. A `!` in front of the pattern means that the condition is true when the regex *doesn't* match (like in the third condition). A `!` inside the pattern is just a literal symbol.

The host conditions should be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcsite\.com$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abcsite\.com$ [NC]
```

And in fact, they can be joined into a single condition (note, no `[OR]` here):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?abcsite\.com$ [NC]
```

Your third condition is intended to prevent redirect loops (`/foo` → `/abc/foo` → `/abc/abc/foo` → …). What it says is that the rule isn't applied if the request URL starts with `/abc/`. However, your actual redirect is an internal redirect: if a user accesses `abcsite.com/foo`, the server internally rewrites this to `/webroot/abc/foo`, but `REQUEST_URI` stays the same, `/foo`.

The reason this doesn't cause a redirect loop as it is is likely rewrite rules in `abc/.htaccess` which override this one once the redirect is done.

What should be checked instead in the third condition is the path matched by the rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^abc/
RewriteRule (.*) /abc/$1 [L]
```